# $C*$-algebra Identity for Matrices

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

What's the easiest way to see that the $n \times n$-matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ satisfy the $C^*$-algebra identity $\|aa^*\| = \|a\|^2$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ be the inner product of $\mathbb{C}^n$ (or any Hilbert space), with corresponding norm $\| \cdot \|$ and let $T$ be an $n \times n$ matrix (or bounded linear operator).

Then by properties of inner products, we have $| \langle x, y \rangle| \le \|x\| \|y\|$.

In particular, $\|x \| = \sup \{ | \langle x, y \rangle| : \|y \| \le 1 \}$.

Thus we can write the operator norm of $T$ as
$$ \|T\| = \sup \{ \|Tx\| : \|x\| \le 1\}  = \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \sup_{\|y\|\le 1} | \langle  Tx, y \rangle|.$$

So
\begin{align}
\|T^*T\| &=& \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \sup_{\|y\|\le 1} |\langle T^*Tx, y \rangle | \\ 
&=& \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \sup_{\|y\|\le 1} |\langle Tx, Ty \rangle| \\
&\geq& \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} |\langle Tx, Tx \rangle| \\
&=& \|T\|^2 \\
\end{align}

But also
\begin{align}
\|T^*T\| &=& \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \sup_{\|y\|\le 1} |\langle T^*Tx, y \rangle| \\ 
&=& \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \sup_{\|y\|\le 1} |\langle Tx, Ty \rangle| \\
&\le& \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \sup_{\|y\|\le 1} \|Tx\| \|Ty\| \\
&=& \|T\|^2.
\end{align}

Comment: I thought the norm on $\mathbb C^{n \times n}$ should be a submultiplicative norm with $\| 1 \| = 1$ (cf. Murphy - C$*$ algebras and operator theory, p. 36). On $\mathbb C^{n \times n}$ the only inner product I know is $\langle A, B \rangle := \text{tr}(A^{\mathsf{H}} B)$. The corresponding norm is the Frobenius norm $\| A \|_F := \text{tr}(A^{\mathsf{H}} A)$, which doesn't have either of the two properties I listed above. So how does this apply the question asked?